# Using signals and sigpipe

Tags: c, process, pipe, signals, sigpipe

I'm working on an assignment that involves writing a program to process data (calculate pi) using fork (processes), signals and select.

I'm working right now on the signals and what I think I want to do is to use SIGPIPE so if the  programs catches it, it tries to write to the pipe again (If a process tries to write to a pipe that has no reader, it will be sent the SIGPIPE).

I use fork() in main() to assign each process the same work by sending them to the worker function.

```
void worker(int id) {
    .... (this piece of code is not relevant)

    if(write(pfd[id][1], &c, sizeof(c)) == -1)
        printf("Error occurred: %s\n",strerror(errno));

}
```

How can I implement signals in this function to catch SIGPIPE and make it write to the pipe again?

Thank you!

Comment: You should go back and accept answers for questions that you've asked.  People are unlikely to answer your questions since you don't accept answers for them.

Comment: oh sorry! i'll do that. EDIT: done! i'm new to this site and how it works but i got it now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically, instead of catching `SIGPIPE` one ignores it, which causes `write` to fail with `EPIPE` instead of silently terminating your program.

**However:** If you are getting a `SIGPIPE` when you write to a pipe, then do not try again.  It will never work.  `SIGPIPE` means that the pipe has no reader -- and if the pipe has no reader now, it will never have a reader.  (Think about it this way: how would a pipe with no reader get one?  It is impossible!)

Your problem is that you are closing the other end of the pipe.  Fix that, and don't worry about `SIGPIPE`.  `SIGPIPE` is just the symptom.

**Edit:** There are two questions to answer here.  If you can't answer *both* of these questions, then don't bother handling `SIGPIPE`.

1. **What would cause my program to receive `SIGPIPE`?**  The only way to receieve `SIGPIPE` is for the reading end of the pipe to get closed.  This happens if the reading process crashes, or if it is programmed to close the pipe.  If you are writing a network server, or communicating with an unknown process, this might be common.  However, if you write both programs, both run locally, then it probably indicates a programming error.
2. **What would my program do when it catches `SIGPIPE`?**  If you are writing a client process that uses a pipe to communicate with a server, then what are you supposed to do with `SIGPIPE`? You can't try again, and clients usually can't restart the server they're connected to.  Just do the sensible, default thing and let `SIGPIPE` terminate your program.  However, if the server is sending data to a client it controls and gets `SIGPIPE`, it *could* restart the client.  But this might be a very bad idea -- for example, if the client is deterministic, it will just crash again, and you will end up with an infinite loop rather than a simple crash.

So the general maxim here is "**Only catch errors you are prepared to handle.**"  Don't catch errors just for the sake of completeness.  Just let them crash your program, or cause the operation to fail, and you can go back and debug it later.

**Code snippet:** This is a snippet of code from one of my projects.  If you run it, `SIGPIPE` will not terminate your process.  Instead, `write` will generate an `EPIPE` error.  If you are writing a network server, then `EPIPE` is one possible way that a client might suddenly disconnect.

```
void
ignore_sigpipe(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    int r;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    r = sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, NULL);
    if (r)
        err(1, "sigaction");
}
```

Comment: My program is working fine and i'm not getting any errors (not even SIGPIPE). I was thinking about "if i ever get SIGPIPE"

Comment: If you're not getting `SIGPIPE`, then why do you need to handle it?

Comment: I don't know, but if the program would be distributed for a lot of computers and one of those gets SIGPIPE I would be a good programmer by preventing these cases. That's what I think. If I'm not right then tell me :)

Comment: @andrepcg Terminaning on sigpipe is usually good behavior. For example in `cat bigfile | grep -v ballast | head -n 100` it is correct that grep and cat terminate when they receive `SIGPIPE`. Otherwise they would either hang or process rest of the big file unnecessarily.

Comment: `It is impossible!` What about named pipes?

Comment: @user185953: The question is about pipes, not fifos.

Comment: @DietrichEpp My mistake. I thought I can use linkat() to name unnamed pipes, but that would be insecure, because I would be able to linkat() my reading end of a pipe, chmod 666, open O_WRONLY and I would get the writing end.