# How to find which file descriptor causing SIGPIPE?

Tags: signals

When the signal handling function of SIGPIPE is triggered, how to retrieve which file descriptor causing it? Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774569/using-signals-and-sigpipe).  Dietrich describes that if you ignore SIGPIPE, then you'll get EPIPE returned from the read or write function, and will thus know the file descriptor that is encountering the error.